# I am getting this error "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" in my node.js code. How to resolve this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, undefined

I am not able to resolve this error. when i am trying to split the request raw Headers it is showing this error. although split is javascript method and why this error comes?

```js
app.get('/redirect', (req, res) => {
  var platform = req.rawHeaders[11];
  var lang = req.rawHeaders[25];
  var language = lang.split(',')[0];


  if (platform.indexOf('Windows') || platform.indexOf('Android') !== -1) {
    if (language === 'en-GB') {
      res.redirect('https://www.google.com/');
    }
    else if (language === 'zh') {
      res.redirect('https://www.youtube.com/');
    }
    else {
      res.status(400).send({ Message: "Language Not Supported" });
    }
  }
  else if (platform.indexOf('Ios') !== -1) {
    if (language === 'en-GB') {
      res.redirect('https://www.amazon.in/');
    }
    else if (language === 'zh') {
      res.redirect('https://www.w3schools.com/');
    }
    else {
      res.status(400).send({ Message: "Language Not Supported" });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: lang may not be getting the value and hence the error message. is this an express app? if so `req.rawHeaders` is not defined in the api. if you want a particular header you can use
https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.get

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `req.rawHeaders[25];` is giving null.

try console log the lang variable and run the API call again

```
console.log(lang)
```

this will give you null or undefined as the output.

you are trying to use the split method on something which does not exist.
if you know the key of that header. use that instead of the index.

header index may change if you add additional fields, or some packages/libraries might set headers. then it's index might change.